# How to remove the sort key of a table in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am stuck with removing sort key in dynamodb table.
I need to know via AWS console UI or command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A DynamoDB table's Sort Key and Partition Key definitions cannot be changed.

(You can update an individual record's PK and SK *values*, but you cannot change the PK or SK setting.)

It is a typical pattern to use the generic key names `PK` and `SK`, for this reason (and that the pattern also enables a [single-table design](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-single-table-design-with-amazon-dynamodb/)).